# Compare groupby output for different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

What could be a way to compare multiple groupby outputs.

I have multiple groupby outputs from different dataframes, like below

```
>>> tmp1
  account place  balance type
0       A    A1       10   B1
1       A    A1       20   B1
2       A    A1       30   B1
3       A    A1       10   B4
4       A    A1       20   B4
5       A    A1       10   B5
6       A    A1       10   B6
7       B    A2       10   B7
8       B    A2       20   B1
9       B    A2      100   B1
```

I do

```
    >>>tmp1.groupby(['account','place','type']['balance'].last().sum(level=0).astype(int)
    account
    A        70
    B        110
    Name: balance, dtype: int64

Similarly
>>> tmp2
  account place  balance type
0       A    A1      100   B1
1       A    A1      200   B1
2       A    A1      100   B1
3       A    A1      100   B4
4       A    A1      200   B4
5       A    A1      100   B5
6       A    A1      100   B6
7       B    A2      100   B7
8       B    A2      200   B1
9       B    A2      200   B1


    >>>tmp2.groupby(['account','place','type']['balance'].last().sum(level=0).astype(int)
    account
    A        500
    B        300
    Name: balance, dtype: int64

    #similarly tmp3 grouped..and so on
```

Is there a way to find the df with maximum sum balance. eg. in this case tmp2 has greater sum `(70+110 < 500+300)`.

My try:
One of the ways I tried was taking the sum and maintaining a list, like below

```
mylist=[]
mylist.append(tmp1.groupby(['account','place','type']['balance'].last().sum(.astype(int))
mylist.append(tmp2.groupby(['account','place','type']['balance'].last().sum(.astype(int))
>>> mylist
[180,800]
```

Now I can take max from list, but I loose account information (800 is max but I need info on account A having 500, B having 300)

I tried

```
>>>tmp2.groupby(['account','place','type'])['balance'].last().sum(level=0).to_dict()
{'A': 500, 'B': 300}
```

So for every df I have a dict, I just need to find maximum of such lists (I think I have come very close to solving it)

I intend to find which dataframe had maximum sum (along with account)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, in case you have more than 2 dfs.

```
tmp1 = pd.DataFrame([{'acount':'A', 'balance':100, 'type':'A1'},
               {'acount':'A', 'balance':200, 'type':'A2'},
              {'acount':'B', 'balance':200, 'type':'B1'},
               {'acount':'B', 'balance':300, 'type':'B2'}])
tmp2 = pd.DataFrame([{'acount':'A', 'balance':100, 'type':'A1'},
               {'acount':'A', 'balance':200, 'type':'A2'},
              {'acount':'B', 'balance':400, 'type':'B1'},
               {'acount':'B', 'balance':300, 'type':'B2'}])
tmplist = [tmp1,tmp2]
tmprlist = [tmp.groupby(['acount','type']).last().sum(level=0).astype(int) for tmp in tmplist]
tmpslist = [tmp.groupby(['acount','type'])['balance'].last().sum() for tmp in tmplist]
tmprlist[np.argmax(tmpslist)]
```

Result:

```
acount  balance
A       300
B       700
```